# Store hexadecimal integers in byte array in Swift (retaining hex format)

Tags: ios, swift, hex

I have to send a byte array of hexadecimal integers to a BLE devise. Whenever I try to use **0x** notation the internal value stored in the byte array is getting converted to a decimal value.

`var foo : [Byte] = [0xff, 0xD9]` is actually stored as `[255, 217]`

What data structure should I be using to make it stay in hex format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep **bytes** in a byte array and what do they mean is up for your interpretation. So what you are keeping there are bytes of value 255 and 217 in base10 and 0xFF and 0xD9 in base16. They are actually kept as 1111 1111 and 1101 1001 in base2. ([Computer number format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format))

You can safely send your byte array without any changes.

If you want to print out your bytes in hexadecimal you can go with something like this:

```
println (foo.map { String($0, radix: 16, uppercase: false) })
```